# How to validate Gmail ids in a text box using ASP.NET RegularExpressionValidator

Tags: asp.net, regex, webforms

Problem:-I want to validate an email id text box..**I want to block Gmail id users**

Eg:-

- abcd@yahoo.com  =>Ok
- abcd@xmail.com  =>Ok
- abcd@hotmail.com  =>Ok
- abcd@gmail.com  =>Not Ok

If any user entering Gmail id in the text box..the error msg will appear..??

already tried using

```
\w+([-+.']\w+)*@(?:gmail).com
```

But it Used for selecting only Gmail ids..I want negation of this..

Comment: Validating e-mail addresses is, in general, ripe for disappointment. There are so many very unusual/uncommon yet still valid addresses (see http://davidcel.is/blog/2012/09/06/stop-validating-email-addresses-with-regex/ for a great discussion).  That being said, if all you are looking for is whether it ends in "@gmail.com" (and has something before the "@") that's a pretty simple thing to implement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change (?: ) to (?! ) to match if content of ( ) is not present:

```
\w+([-+.']\w+)*@(?!gmail).com
```

This will not match abcd@gmail.com, but will fail also on abcd@yahoo.com because no other characters allowed between @ and .com

To keep gmail.com blocked and to allow other domains change pattern to

```
\w+([-+.']\w+)*@((?!gmail\.com).*)
```

Note that when you have [-+.'] you tell to allow -,+,. and ' in the email address. Minus and dots are allowed but not plus and apostrophe.

So, finally

```
\w+([-.]\w+)*@((?!gmail\.com).*)
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you can use negation of that

```
\w+([-+.']\w+)*@(?:gmail).com
```

In an if block check the email using this and take the negation..I think it will work

Answer (score 0):

Try below regular expression:

```
\b[\w\.-]+@((?!gmail).)[\w\.-]+\.\w{2,4}\b
```